# Upload image in Wordpress with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image-uploading

I'm tring upload an image on wordpress front end.
I built my form where there is:

```
<input type="file" name="choose_file" id="choose_file" />
```

And then on click, starts this jquery code:

```
jQuery('#upload_temp_image_results').load(pathname, {'image': jQuery('#choose_file').val()});
```

Finally the uploader.php:

```
if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) require_once('../../../../wp-admin/includes/file.php');

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $expire = $_POST['expire'];
    echo 'a<img src="'.$image.'"/>a';
    echo $image;
    echo $expire;

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($image, array( 'test_form' => false ));
    if ($movefile) 
    {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile);
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
```

My problem is that i get this error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cancellare\wp-admin\includes\file.php on line 13**

What's wrong?
I need to use my custom form and i can't use wordpress uploader (which is used in admin area).

Comment: You cannot upload a file like that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: Wordpress has a perfectly good media uploader already built in. Learn to use that instead.

Comment: Musa: thanks.i didn't find before that link!

Comment: Adeneo: i'm able to use wp media uploader, but as i wrote in my post, "I need to use my custom form and i can't use wordpress uploader"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use WP functions, u must to load wp-load.php from root folder of ur wordpress install.
And only then, if it's not allready included by wp-load.php, u must include such file's as file.php

Comment: Ok, it works! I'd like to undestand better: what's wp-load.php content?

Comment: wp-load.php loading all WP functionality. In ur case, error calling **__()**  function - l10n function from translate WP. After WP-Load.php u can use all WP functions and variables, such as $wp_query, $wp_db and else.